# Align with center div elements included in a hierarchy

Tags: css, html

I've the following structure in one of my webpages :

```
<div class="id1">
        <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="id2 block">
                    </div>
                    <div class="id3 block">
                    </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to have the div elements id2 and id3 centered. I've tried to use a div element with align=center but so far it only centered the text inside id2 and id3 and not the elements id2 and id3.

Comment: Give the auto margin for left and right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

Use `margin: 1em auto;`

The `1em` is the top `margin`, the `auto` calculates the side margins and equally applies.

Note: a `width` must be set on the `div` for this to work.

```
div.wrapper{border:1px solid green; width:400px; height:400px;}
div.id2, div.id3 {border:1px solid red; width:200px; height:100px; 
                  margin:1em auto;}
```

*Borders and stuff for example only:*

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/DgZza/

Answer (score 1):

use this CSS:

```
margin: auto;
```

This is a technique for centering horizontally.

And some recommendations:

1. Avoid creating styles through HTML attributes like `align='center'`
2. `id2` and `id3` are unique identifiers for you div elements. Move them to `id` attribute instead of using them as a class. Class simply means grouping more than one element.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that you need a width set on the divs in order for margin: auto; to work